# wget fails to resolve host/node name after 1 file download

Tags: linux, unix, wget

I've recently been trying to download a large number of files from a website with wget, and my problem is that once I have downloaded one file, I receive the following error message.

```
--2012-06-28 14:08:28--  http://./
Resolving .... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `.'
FINISHED --2012-06-28 14:08:28--
Total wall clock time: 1m 50s
Downloaded: 189 files, 76M in 1m 28s (886 KB/s)
```

The command that I used was:

```
wget --user=*MyUserName* --password=*MyPassword* -m --accept=zip --reject=*med*,*sml*,*sd* http://website/dir/files /volumes/Drive/Folder
```

Can anyone offer me a way to fix this? I've tried multiple Q&As, but no one has been experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your command doesn't do what you think it does. In particular, the syntax for invoking `wget` is

```
wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

This means that all the non-option arguments are supposed to be URLs, which means that `wget` interprets `/volumes/Drive/Folder` as a URL to fetch (which isn't what you meant, of course). I don't know of a `wget` option to set a destination directory offhand, and a cursory search of the `wget` manual didn't turn up anything obvious, so I'd suggest just changing to your desired destination directory before running `wget`.